# Searching in a specific folder of Google Drive on Android

Tags: google-drive

Since 2018 Google allows one to search within specific folders of Google drive.

e.g. The answer here:

[In Google Drive, is there a way to search files located in a particular folder?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/40006/in-google-drive-is-there-a-way-to-search-files-located-in-a-particular-folder)

But can I do this on the Google Drive app on my Android Phone as well?

Answer (score 0):

No, searching by folder is not currently allowed in the mobile versions of Google Drive. [It's unclear](https://9to5google.com/2018/01/09/google-drive-folder-search/) if Google is planning on adding it to the mobile versions.